# SceneKit – Application is getting crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scenekit

I am creating a 3d app using SceneKit and DAE files. My app is getting crash on:

```
SCNView *myView = (SCNView *)self.view;
myView.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"p1.dae"];
myView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
myView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = YES;
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

reason behind crash is  reason:

> -[UIView setScene:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9338f2ca20

Can you please tell me what is the problem with code?

Answer (score 1):

looks like you instantiated a UIView in your xib file instead of an SCNView. You can drag and drop an SCNView from the Objects library in the lower-right corner of Xcode.